# How to get the text of a selected item in a select control?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
 <select name="DropList" id="serverDropList"> 
  <option selected="selected" value="2">server1:3000</option> 
  <option value="5">server3:3000</option> 
 </select>
```

i know in prototype i can get value by `$('serverDropList').value` but how can i get "server1:3000" ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think Prototype has any shortcut that does that for you, so:

```
var box = $('serverDropList');
var text = box.selectedIndex >= 0 ? box.options[box.selectedIndex].innerHTML : undefined;
```

...gives you the `innerHTML` of the selected option, or `undefined` if there is none.

If you like, you can use [`Element#addMethods`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/addmethods/) to define this once and have it available on all of your select boxes:

```
Element.addMethods("SELECT", (function() {
    function getSelectedOptionHTML(element) {
        if (!(element = $(element))) return;
        var index = element.selectedIndex;
        return index >= 0 ? element.options[index].innerHTML : undefined;
    }

    return {
        getSelectedOptionHTML: getSelectedOptionHTML
    };
})());
```

Usage:

```
var text = $('serverDropList').getSelectedOptionHTML();
```

I used a named function when defining that. If you're not bothered about named functions (I am, I [always use them](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html)), you can make it a bit simpler:

```
Element.addMethods("SELECT", {
    getSelectedOptionHTML: function(element) {
        if (!(element = $(element))) return;
        var index = element.selectedIndex;
        return index >= 0 ? element.options[index].innerHTML : undefined;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 25):

If you are using Prototype, you may use:

```
var text = $('serverDropList')[$('serverDropList').selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: THis should be the RIGHT answer. Perfect

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry if i am late with this answer, but i was looking into the same problem and i wasn't satisfied with this answer, so i dug for a better answer:

Prototype has the following selector that you can use in order cu get the selected value of your list: $F.
So in you example situation, it should work the following code:

```
$F('serverDropList'); -- this for getting the value
$F('serverDropList').text; -- this for getting the text
```

Comment: this is much nicer.. is there a way to mash that together with a `this` created by an onchange?

Comment: I'm not very sure if this function is supported for all the browsers, so you could check that, otherwise you could have made a mistake, submit a fiddle so i can help your cause

Answer (score 2):

```
function getSelectedValue( obj ) {
    return obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Usage:

```
<select onchange="alert(getSelectedValue(this););" id="mySelect">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

or

```
getSelectedValue(document.getElementById('mySelect'));
```

or (when using prototype or jquery)

```
getSelectedValue($('mySelect'));
```

Comment: This does not return the text value, but the `value` property of the selected item. The OP was asking for the text value of the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Select the second choice:

```
<select onchange="alert(getSelectedValue(this););" id="mySelect">
  <option> value="1" city="chicago"> one </option>
  <option> value="2" city="orlando"> two </option>
</select>
```

I need to pick the item value city.